# What is a Ruby equivalent for Python's "zip" builtin?

Tags: python, ruby, translation

Is there any Ruby equivalent for Python's builtin `zip` function? If not, what is a concise way of doing the same thing?

A bit of context: this came up when I was trying to find a clean way of doing a check involving two arrays. If I had `zip`, I could have written something like:

```
zip(a, b).all? {|pair| pair[0] === pair[1]}
```

I'd also accept a clean way of doing this without anything resembling `zip` (where "clean" means "without an explicit loop").

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Ruby has a zip function:

```
[1,2].zip([3,4]) => [[1,3],[2,4]]
```

so your code example is actually:

```
a.zip(b).all? {|pair| pair[0] === pair[1]}
```

or perhaps more succinctly:

```
a.zip(b).all? {|a,b| a === b }
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you not do:

```
a.eql?(b)
```

Edited to add an example:

```
a = %w[a b c]
b = %w[1 2 3]
c = ['a', 'b', 'c']

a.eql?(b) # => false
a.eql?(c) # => true
a.eql?(c.reverse) # => false
```

Comment: I'm not sure. I need to use the === equivalence operator to compare elements, not ==.

Answer (score -2):

This is from the ruby spec:

```
it "returns true if other has the same length and each pair of corresponding elements are eql" do
    a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    b = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    a.should eql(b)
    [].should eql([])
end
```

So you should it should work for the example you mentioned.

If you're not using integers, but custom objects I *think* you need to override eql?.

The spec for this method is here:

http://github.com/rubyspec/rubyspec/tree/master/1.8/core/array/eql_spec.rb