# Best way to iterate over multiple arrays?

Tags: ruby, arrays, loops

What's is the best (beauty and efficient in terms of performance) way to iterate over multiple arrays in Ruby?
Let's say we have an arrays:

```
a=[x,y,z]
b=['a','b','c']
```

and I want this:

```
x a
y b
z c
```

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the 'Ruby way' to iterate over two arrays at once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3580049/whats-the-ruby-way-to-iterate-over-two-arrays-at-once)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `zip` method on array objects:

```
a.zip b do |items|
    puts items[0], items[1]
end
```

Comment: You could also so something like `a.zip(b) { |first, second| p [first, second] }` instead of indexing `items`.

Answer (score 6):

An alternative is using `each_with_index`. A quick benchmark shows that this is slightly faster than using zip.

```
a.each_with_index do |item, index|
  puts item, b[index]
end
```

Benchmark:

```
a = ["x","y","z"]
b = ["a","b","c"]

Benchmark.bm do |bm|
  bm.report("ewi") do
    10_000_000.times do
      a.each_with_index do |item, index|
        item_a = item
        item_b = b[index]
      end
    end
  end
  bm.report("zip") do
    10_000_000.times do
      a.zip(b) do |items|
        item_a = items[0]
        item_b = items[1]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Results:

```
      user     system      total        real
ewi  7.890000   0.000000   7.890000 (  7.887574)
zip 10.920000   0.010000  10.930000 ( 10.918568)
```

Comment: Was this under MRI (1.8) or YARV (1.9)?

Comment: ruby 1.9.2p136 (2010-12-25 revision 30365) [x86_64-darwin10.6.0]

Answer (score 2):

```
>> a=["x","y","z"]
=> ["x", "y", "z"]
>> b=["a","b","c"]
=> ["a", "b", "c"]
>> a.zip(b)
=> [["x", "a"], ["y", "b"], ["z", "c"]]
>>
```

Answer (score 1):

See [What is a Ruby equivalent for Python's "zip" builtin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263623/what-is-a-ruby-equivalent-for-pythons-zip-builtin)

Answer (score 1):

I like to use transpose when iterating through multiple arrays using Ruby. Hope this helps.

```
bigarray = []
bigarray << array_1
bigarray << array_2
bigarray << array_3
variableName = bigarray.transpose

variableName.each do |item1,item2,item3|

# do stuff per item
# eg 
puts "item1"
puts "item2"
puts "item3"

end
```